# How to parse a JSON with a property which could be a String or an Object using GSON?

Tags: java, gson

I have a class that should be deserialized accordingly the header request.

If header is on V1 version, ww should output the information field of Product class, like a String. Otherwise it output an Info object.

Is there another solution to do this, instead duplicate the class?

```
public class Product{   
  private String name;
  private Integer id;
  private Info information;
 }


 public class Info{ 
    private String generalInfo;
    private String fullDescription;
    private String code;
  }


public class Product{   
  private String name;
  private Integer id;
  private String information;
 }
```

Above the JSON when use INFO object and when information is a string.

```
{
    "name": "Paul",
    "id": "123123,
    "information": {
        "generalInfo":"Business Product",
        "fullDescription":"23",
        "code":"9487987289929222-3"
    }
}

{
    "name": "Paul",
    "id": "123123,
    "information": "Business Product - 23 - 9487987289929222-3 "
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. It seems you want to serialize an `Info` object in both situations.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis i edited the code... follow anoter example of information field like a String

Comment: If you know beforehand which kind of response you are going to get, the most pragmatic way is probably to, as you suggested, have two classes `ProductWithInfoString` and `ProductWithInfoObject`. If you don't like the code duplication make an abstract class `ProductInfo<T>` that has a `private T information` and subclass it with `T` being either `String` or `Info`. If you don't know ahead of time and need to decide during the parsing process, I think you'll need your own `TypeAdapterFactory`.

Comment: It would be helpful here to include a sample JSON string

Comment: @durron597 i put the JSON examples on question... thanks !

Comment: How can you have two different classes both named `Product`?